# C -swap 2 chars recursively with only one pointer

Tags: c

I need to write a function:
void swap (char * s1, char * s2);

The function will replace the contents of both strings 1s and 2s.
Constraints:
In the function, **there is no use of [] anywhere**, but performance by working with pointers, in addition, trips must be made with the voters, meaning that they will actually move to another cell as needed, and will not remain in the same location all the time.
• **No loops** in the function, that is, work in recursion.

I did the function with pointer to pointer str** but must change it to **only one pointer str and recursively**. How can I change it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char *str1="abc",*str2="xyz",*pRev;
 swap(&str1, &str2); 
 printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s", str1, str2); 
 getchar(); 
  return 0;
}
//need *str NOT **str
  void swap(char **str1, char **str2);
    char * RevWords (char * str, int size);
    void swap(char **str1, char **str2) 
    { 
      char *temp = *str1_ptr; 
      *str1_ptr = *str2_ptr; 
      *str2_ptr = temp; 
    }
```

after swap method:

str2="abc", str1="xyz"

Comment: I'm guessing you are expected to swap individual characters (e.g.: `char temp = *s1; *s1 = *s2; *s2 = temp;`) - however that doesn't work with string literals, you'll have to make copies of those strings first

Comment: Unless the homework guarantees that the strings are the same length, or that the pointers (s1 and s2) point to sufficient memory to hold either string, then your first task is to allocate memory.

Comment: "_trips must be made with the voters, meaning that they will actually move to another cell as needed, and will not remain in the same location all the time_" what are you speaking about ?

Comment: to not have literal const string replace  `char *str1="abc",*str2="xyz"` by `char str1[]="abc", str2[]="xyz";`

Comment: _The function will replace the contents of both strings 1s and 2s._ currently you do not exchange the contains of the strings but just the pointers to them

Answer (score 0):

Well this is clearly not an ideal solution but gives you something to work with.
However this will only work (as mentioned above) when you have the same length of strings (or yes, you'll have to allocate memory + you'd need to know the length of your strings). But otherwise I think this may answer your question.

This is working with recursion and depends on the fact that both strings are the same length and containing a zero character at the end of each one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    // if both of them are zero characters then stop
    if (*str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0')
        return;
    // else swap the contents of the pointers
    else
    {
        char tmp = *str1;
        *str1 = *str2;
        *str2 = tmp;
        // advance both pointer and swap them too if thye are not '\0'
        swap(++str1, ++str2);        
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "abc\0\0\0"; // padded with zeros to be the same length as str2
    char str2[] = "xyz123"; // the last '\0' is automatically added

    swap(str1, str2);
    printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s", str1, str2);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```